# Better way to calculate string formula in excel 2016/O365?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365

GOAL: evaluate "2 Days 16 Hours 30 Minutes" to seconds.

I searched the web and found no fitting answer, i desire a 100% formula solution. Limitations: no VBA, avoid name manager, only day/hour/minute, spaces exist.

current solution i have working:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this SUM as an Array Formula:

```
=SUM(
  (ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Day",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($XFD$1:INDEX(XFD:XFD,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1)))*999,999)))))*(IFERROR(60*60*24*TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($XFD$1:INDEX(XFD:XFD,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1))-1)*999+1,999)),0))
+ (ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Hour",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($XFD$1:INDEX(XFD:XFD,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1)))*999,999)))))*(IFERROR(60*60*TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($XFD$1:INDEX(XFD:XFD,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1))-1)*999+1,999)),0))
+ (ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Minute",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($XFD$1:INDEX(XFD:XFD,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1)))*999,999)))))*(IFERROR(60*TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($XFD$1:INDEX(XFD:XFD,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1))-1)*999+1,999)),0))
)
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when Exiting edit mode.

This iterates each word in the string.  If it finds `Day(s)`,`Hour(s)`,Or `Minute(s)`  It does the proper multiplication with the number in front of that word.  Then it adds the results.

[image]

Comment: i forgot to mention that i desire to avoid array formulas so i accept the answer. Nice & quick reply!

Comment: It cannot be done without array or array type formula, vba, or using evaluate in the name manager.